# Render MathJax in review queues

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

I just reviewed a [suggested edit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/6219). It was fine, but I have to say it would have been quite useful to see the **actual** rendered output instead of text and the raw MathJax I saw.

I saw this:

[image: mathjax raw text]

I'd like to see this:

[image: what i want]

and

[image: what i want]

---

There are a couple of options for how the review is rendered, currently "rendered output" and "markdown":

[image: options]

I propose that in the "rendered output" display, the MathJax should be rendered as above; in the "markdown" display it should show as the raw text.

What do we think?

Comment: Ooh, yeah, that would help.  We're not the first site to do MathJax; anybody want to poke around on the others' metas to see if they solved this problem?  Is it just a switch that SE needs to flip for us, or is it status-declined all over the place?  (I hope the former.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Physics [suggested this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5592/how-can-i-see-rendered-mathjax-latex-when-reviewing-edits) a long time ago but the request has no status tag

Comment: Yes, please! I had the same issue with reviewing the same edit.

Comment: The note text is slightly off; it doesn't actually have an *answer* at the linked duplicate, but the question appears to be about exactly the same issue.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'm aware of that post; I posted this because that one is an old bug that doesn't appear to have been fixed or declined or anything. I'd like to see this happen so I made this as a feature request.